# Action of a finite group on finite set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need help to answer the following problem:

> Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a finite set $X$. Let $m$ be a number of orbits of $G$ on $X$ and $M$ be the number of orbits of $G$ on $X\times X$. Show that $m^2\le M$ with equality if and only if G acts trivialy on $X$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $G .(x,y) \subseteq (G.x) \times (G.y)$.

**Hint 2** For equality you need to get equality above for all $x,y$. 
Use the fact that $(g.x,e.y) \in (G.x) \times (G.y)$.

Comment: exactly the professor gave to us this two hints but i am not able to solve the problem, I will be gratfull if you could help me.

Comment: @naima The first hint tells you that an orbit on $X \times X$ is included in a pair of orbits on $X$. How many different pairs of orbits are there?

Comment: there are $m^2$?

Comment: @naima Exactly. Now you have to figure out why does this solve the first part.

Comment: i dont know why?